# Covering of open set by compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. Now I was wondering: I need to use the following property that for this open set we have $K_n \subset \Omega$ compact such that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{int}(K_n) = \Omega$? But why does this hold or is there an easy way to see it without using difficult constructions?

Okay, maybe I give it a try by what has been answered so far. We definitely assume that Omega is non-empty and then we pick:

$$K_n :=\{x\in \Omega: d(x,\partial \Omega)\geq \frac{1}{n}\} \cap \overline{B(0,n)}$$

now those guys are bounded and approximate $\Omega$ in a way. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks right to me. You just need to be careful in the cases where $\partial \Omega$ is empty as Mariano points out.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to see it is that the $K_n$ are compact sets nested inside $\Omega$ getting larger and larger. Namely: $$K_n :=\{x\in \Omega: d(x,\partial \Omega)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}\cap \overline{B_n}$$ where $\overline{B_n}$ is the closed ball of radius $n$. Using the convention that $d(x,\emptyset)=\infty$ for any $x$.

Comment: This only works under some boundedness conditions. If $\Omega$ is a half plane, for example, your sets are not compact. And, of course, for it to even make sense you need $\partial\Omega$ to be non-empty!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since $\Omega$ is open, $d(x, \partial \Omega) > 0$ for all $x \in \Omega$. So, consider the sets $$K_n := \left\{x \in \Omega : d(x, \partial \Omega) \geq \frac{1}{n}\right\} \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| \leq n\}.$$ By construction (1) each $K_n$ is closed and bounded (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) hence compact, and the union of the $K_n$ is exactly $\Omega$.

Comment: Your $K_n$ is in general not contained in $\Omega$.

Comment: Cheers, Mariano, somehow I read over that hypothesis.