# Open Set in $\mathbf{R}^n$ can be Covered by Countable Union of Compact Sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

I am aware of a couple answers, such as this one: [Covering of open set by compact sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197925/covering-of-open-set-by-compact-sets). My question is why exactly are the sets $$K_n := \{ x \in E: \operatorname{dist}(x, E^c) \geq \frac{1}{n}, \| x \| = d(0, x) \le n \}$$ closed with $E \subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$ being an open set? Is there a way to easily see this without using the sequential proof of a closed set (i.e. the limit of a sequence inside of a closed set stays inside)?

Comment: As written, it's not.  the last inequality should be $\leq$.  Then it's fairly easy to prove (using the triangle inequality) that the complement of $K_n$ is open.

Comment: Even if I assume your $E$ is supposed to be $\Omega$ from the link, your set is very different from the one they write there. In the link, they look at the distance from the boundary $\partial E$, not the complement $E^c$, and also then they intersect with the *closed* ball of radius $n$, i.e. you should have a non-strict inequality $\le n$ there. With these fixed, $K_n$ the intersection of two sets, one of which (the closed ball) is obviously closed, and all that's left to show is that the other one is, which is also not hard.

Comment: The original question has a much easier answer that you can obtain by thinking about points in $E$ (or $\Omega$) with rational coordinates and closed balls around those points with rational radii.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\operatorname{dist}\left(x,E^\complement\right)$ and let $g(x)=\|x\|$. Then $f$ and $g$ are continuous. Therefore, since $\left[\frac1n,\infty\right)$ and $[0,n]$ are closed sets, then so are the sets$$f^{-1}\left(\left[\frac1n,\infty\right)\right)=\left\{x\in E\,\middle|\,f(x)\geqslant\frac1n\right\}\tag1$$and$$g^{-1}\bigl([0,n]\bigr)=\left\{x\in E\,\middle|\,\right\|x\|\leqslant n\}.\tag2$$And your set is the intersection of $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

A general topology approach that avoids the metric: $\Bbb R^n$ is locally compact Hausdorff. These properties both inherit to open subspaces $O$.  Also, $\Bbb R^n$ is second countable and hence so is $O$. By Hausdorff local compactness of $O$, we can cover $O$ by open sets $U_x$ with $\overline{U_x} \subseteq O$ and such that the closure is compact. As $O$ is Lindelöf (implied by second countability), we can reduce these to a countable subcover and the corresponding closures are the required cover by countably many compact sets of $O$.